# Xampp - access to subdirectory using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have created a folder `mymvc` in `htdocs` folder
Now i have a directory structure

```
|htdocs
       |--mymvc
               |--public
                        |--index.php
               |--.htaccess
```

when i enter url : `localhost/mymvc/` in browser, i want request go to `public->index.php` file. I want only public folder is accessible to user.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -l
RewriteRule (?!^public/)^(.*)$ /public/$1 [R=302,L,NC]
```

I put this `htaccess` code but its does not work. it redirect me to `public` folder but does not redirect to `index.php` available in `public` folder.

Comment: it don't make the redirect or it redirect you to something strange ?

Comment: it redirect me to mymvc/index.php. May be the .htaccess is not working

Comment: have you authorize htaccess in apache ? (normaly it's always authorize in XAMP)

Comment: yes htaccess is authorized by apache. i have tested a simple test with htaccess and its working. but my above problem is not working.

Comment: maybe you can try something like that : `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index(\.(html|htm))?)$` because in your code i think a test are missing

Comment: @Inazo it is working now... sorry there i was doing a silly mistake

Comment: don't hesitate to edit your code or post the answer below :)

Comment: 50% problem solved.  actually i deleted index.php from my mymvc folder. then htaccess started redirecting it to public folder. but is not reading the index file inside the public folder